# What does this symbol of $\Longleftrightarrow$ mean?

Tags: logic

What does it mean, is it an implication or does mean something else?

Comment: it means "if and only if"

Answer (score 6):

The symbol $\iff$ in this context means "if and only if". If you have two statements $p$ and $q$, then $p\iff q$ means $p\Rightarrow q$ **and** $q\Rightarrow p$, and consequently that $p$ and $q$ have the same truth values. $$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline p & q & p\Rightarrow q & q\Rightarrow p & p\iff q \\ \hline 
\color{green}1 & \color{#C00}0 & \color{#C00}0 & \color{green}1 & \color{#C00}0 \\
\hline \color{green}1 & \color{green}1 & \color{green}1 & \color{green}1 & \color{green}1 \\
\hline \color{#C00}0 & \color{green}1 & \color{green}1 & \color{#C00}0 & \color{#C00}0 \\
\hline \color{#C00}0 & \color{#C00}0 & \color{green}1 &\color{green}1 &\color{green}1 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 3):

It means "if and only if". Sometimes this is shortened to "iff".
You can translate $P \iff Q$ by ($P \implies Q \text{ and } Q \implies P$).